# Is it possible to access internet on smart-phone through usb (no wi-fi) using Laptop as the modem?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, usb, nokia-pc-suite

One of my relatives has a nokia 5235 smartphone. It is good, but the only limitation is - there is no wifi. bluetooth & usb are the only connectivity options.

His laptop has an unlimited broadband but no support for bluetooth, so basically usb is the only method by which he can connect the mobile with laptop. Now, he can do a file-transfer between these two devices, but by any chance, is there a way by which we can share the Laptop's internet connection through usb to the smart-phone? So, bascially its like this:

Broadband-modem => Laptop =>usb=> smart-phone ->(want to use internet here)

Are there any software or utilities available to achieve this ?

Comment: Does the smartphone support Internet over USB? If so, yes. If not, no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you take a look at [this link](http://devilsworkshop.org/tips/access-internet-from-mobile-using-computers-internet-connection/1016/).

What you are trying to do is a reverse tether, where your phone accesses the internet of your computer. To outline it, you have to have GnuBox on your phone, and install mRouter on your Windows computer.

[image]

Comment: GnuBox is offline as far as I know.

Comment: @ernie I thought the 3235 was Symbian...?

Comment: you're right . . . I removed that part of the comment . . . OP is probably best off googling reverse tethering